# How to mount containers volume(non root user) to root user on host in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

When i am trying to mount application log volume from containers to host
getting error: Operation not permitted

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
  initContainers:
  - name: volume-mount-permission
    image: xx.xx.xx.xx/orchestration/credit-card
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/logs/credit-card
    - chgrp 1000 /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/logs/credit-card
    volumeMounts:
    - name: card-corp-logs
      mountPath: /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/logs/credit-card
      readOnly: false

  containers:
  - name: credit-card
    image: xx.xx.xx.xx/orchestration/credit-card
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      runAsUser: 1000
    ports:
    - name: credit-card
      containerPort: 8080
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
         path: /
         port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 5
      successThreshold: 1
    volumeMounts:
    - name: override-setting-storage
      mountPath: /p/config
    - name: credit-card-teamsite
      mountPath: /var/credit-card/teamsite/card_corp
```

Container Path - /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/logs/credit-card to hostPath

Can anyone please help me out where i am doing mistake in deployment yml file.

Comment: Your `initContainer: command:` is malformed, also; only that `chown -R` will execute; the `chgrp` line below it will be passed into shell as the first argument, and **not** executed; you can confirm this for yourself by running what it is running: `sh -c "echo hello" "echo world"`

Answer (score 1):

```
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
```

means you cannot `chown 1000:1000` because that user is not a member of **group** `1000`

Likely you will want to run that `initContainer:` as `runAsUser: 0` in order to allow it to perform arbitrary `chown` operations

You also truncated your YAML that would have specified the `volumes:` that are being mounted by your `volumeMounts:` -- there is a chance that you are trying to mount a volume type that -- regardless of your `readOnly: false` declaration -- cannot be modified. `ConfigMap`, `Secret`, Downward API, and a bunch of others also will not respond to mutation requests, even as `root`.